# How to populate Lookup textbox value with autofilled values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working with a javascript framework developed for our company's CRM system. I grab a value from the header part of an opportunity page, and when I create a new opportunity part in a frame embedded within the opportunity page, I am storing a value in localStorage, and when a new opportunity part is created, I grab that value from localStorage and autopopulate it to the field in the new row for the part in the frame. However, when I save, the value doesn't get saved... The reason it isn't saved is because usually, a user has to click the lookup button to select a value, upon which it gets populated to the field. What I want ideally is for the lookup image next to the field to be a "X", indicating it was populated, rather than a magnifying glass (which will pop up the lookup window.) Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!
Here is the code i am using :

```
var designprojectid = localStorage.getItem("designprojectid");
var projectname = localStorage.getItem("projectname");
$("#ctlScreenGrid_trakDataGridItem" + rowIdx + "_pt_designprojectid_pt_projectname").val(projectname);
$("#ctlScreenGrid_trakDataGridItem" + rowIdx + "_pt_designprojectid_pt_designprojectid").val(designprojectid);
```

Here is the image:
The top row should have the lookup button as "X" but it is a magnifying glass. i want it to be an "X" otherwise it won't save...

[image: image for opportunity part]

Comment: Just so you know, posting code in addition to your question increases your likelihood of receiving help from the online community.

Comment: Are you setting all 3 - logical name, Id & display name of lookup?

Comment: There's only id and display name available to select and populate via jquery...

Comment: I guess this is strongly customized custom grid & control, not native CRM thing.. probably you are not following the expected syntax.. talk to your team.. I doubt SO can help until unless see the whole project files..

Comment: Thank you Arun... you’re probably right. We only have two people in the US though, and one doesn’t code. Haha, I’ll figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is strongly customized custom grid & other controls, not native CRM thing. Probably you are not following the expected syntax. Please check internally & fix it.